# Twilio IP Messaging: Channel join in Android not working properly

Tags: android, twilio

I'm using Twilio library 0.9.1

I've created a channel and joined it. The unique name of channel is stored in a SQLite database. If I open app later some time, got the channel name from db and using `getChannelByUniqueName` method to get channel object. Before using this channel object for sending and receiving messages, I have to connect.

1. For that connection which method should i use?
2. Now i'm using join method for connecting and call back for join isn't able to get some times?

Using below snippet to join channel:

```
channel.join(new com.twilio.ipmessaging.Constants.StatusListener() {
@Override
public void onSuccess() {
    Utilities.writeToLogFile(Constants.LOG_ERROR_LEVEL, "Joined with channel: " + channel.getUniqueName());
}

@Override
public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
    Utilities.writeToLogFile(Constants.LOG_ERROR_LEVEL, "Error joining channel: " + errorInfo.getErrorText());
}
});
```

The channel object I got from using `getChannelsByUniqueName` method of Channels class. I didn't get callback for join `StatusListener` sometimes. Neither receiver `onSuccess` nor `onError` callbacks.

Logs from library:

11-01 11:37:05.006 15337-17811/com.myorg.myapp E/com.myorg.myapp.util.Utilities: IP Messaging Received completely initialized IPMessagingClient

11-01 11:37:41.866 15337-17929/com.myorg.myapp W/art: Native thread exiting without having called DetachCurrentThread (maybe it's going to use a pthread_key_create destructor?): Thread[71,tid=17929,Native,Thread*=0xb8256a28,peer=0x239810a0,"om.myorg.myapp- 17929"]

11-01 11:37:41.866 15337-17932/com.myorg.myapp W/art: Native thread exiting without having called DetachCurrentThread (maybe it's going to use a pthread_key_create destructor?): Thread[72,tid=17932,Native,Thread*=0xb80d9980,peer=0x239ad1c0,"ne.rolo - 17929 - 17932"]

11-01 11:37:41.876 15337-17931/com.myorg.myapp E/com.myorg.myapp.util.Utilities: ************** MSG SENDING:Yummy

11-01 11:37:41.886 15337-17931/com.myorg.myapp W/art: Native thread exiting without having called DetachCurrentThread (maybe it's going to use a pthread_key_create destructor?): Thread[71,tid=17931,Native,Thread*=0xb831af58,peer=0x23981100,"ne.rolo - 17929 - 17931"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that you have synched your channels before getting the channel.

Something like `client.getChannels().getChannel()` might not work in the 0.9.1 release.

Here are the examples of retrieving channel object: [one](https://github.com/twilio/ip-demo-android/blob/bc1ecd2283497b18531f67c29c02fcd90ecba3c8/ip-messaging-demo-android/src/main/java/com/twilio/ipmessaging/demo/MessageActivity.java#L132) and [two](https://github.com/twilio/ip-demo-android/blob/430031daaaf37babf8c41e50137cb1f94e17d6ab/ip-messaging-demo-android/src/main/java/com/twilio/ipmessaging/demo/ChannelActivity.java#L318)

I'm fixing this and many other listener problems for 0.10.0 release which is coming out real soon.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm retrieving channel object as it's from demo project you've mentioned. I couldn't sync my channel object. Because, synchronize method of Channel isn't working properly. Got crash from JNI so files. ChannelListener too not working properly. Eagerly waiting for 0.10.0. Please let us know when it can be available?

Comment: Can you please post the exact JNI crash you're getting?

Comment: E/jni_mate: ## Fatal error in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ip-messaging-sdk-android-public-release/sdk/build/prebuilt/jni-mate/include/jni_mate.h, line 346
# Check failed: !env->ExceptionCheck()
# GlobalRef.call: Failed to call method by ID
#

Comment: Got the above crash dump sometimes.

Comment: I need log lines preceding the jni log line and following it, too. Full log preferably, this line alone does not give any information.

Comment: Also Please let me know when next of version of twilio library(0.10.0?) will be available?

Comment: Berkus, I m not getting that crash again. For connecting to the channel, I m using channel.synchronize method. I got channel object from onSuccess callback of synchronize method and naming this object as currentChannel. Trying to send message using currentChannel.getMessages().sendMessage() method. I didn't get callback for sent message. Please confirm, is this too you are fixing in next version of library. Logs pasted in query section.

Comment: The problems with callbacks should be fixed in that version indeed, please test. And please, provide full logs from the emulator or device when requesting help - otherwise it's a guessing game. You can post them to gist.github.com or anywhere else (including them here could be problematic).